# Unable to connect pi to windows laptop

Tags: ethernet, windows

I'm trying to connect the Pi to my Windows-based laptop. I'm following [these](http://carbonstone.blogspot.com/2014/02/connecting-to-pi-from-laptops-ethernet.html) instructions.

I don't see the 192.137 interface. I have already rebooted the laptop. What else should I do?

Comment: Does the hostname ping at a different IP?  I didn't read the article I depth, I only scanned it, but it seems like your IP may vary.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What have YOU done? You can't expect us to read a link and guess what you may have done.

Comment: You *don't* need to use ICS. You can connect your Pi directly to your laptop using a common Ethernet cable. Both devices will recognize this and pick a random address in the 169.x.x.x range. To avoid guessing the Pi's address you can configure it to use a static IP. This is described in [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/use-your-desktop-or-laptop-screen-and-keyboard-with-your-pi/)

Comment: The IP address could be different than the 192.168.137.xxx. The important part is do you get an IP address or not? On the RPi type `ip a`, does it show an IP for eth0?

Answer (score 2):

If you can instead connect the Raspberry Pi to the ethernet port on your router, that would allow you to use the following method. You would just need to know the ip address of your RPi.
The local IP address of your Raspberry Pi is not fixed, unless you are using a wireless adapter to connect, which will keep its IP address. If you want to use SSH for the RPI, you can use these steps:

> Start up your Pi to the terminal prompt.  Type the following command
>   "sudo apt-get install xrdp" If promoted enter your password (the
>   default is "raspberry") Type "Y" and press enter. This is now
>   installing xrdp onto your Pi which is the software we are going to use
>   for the remote desktop connection.  Wait for it to complete. Restart
>   your Pi.  We are going to check that xrdp is going to start up
>   automatically. When your Pi has booted to the command prompt look for
>   [ ok ] Starting Remote Desktop Protocol server : xrdp sesman.  This
>   shows you that xrdp is installed and automatically starting up on
>   start up of your Pi The last step is to make a note of the IP address
>   of your Pi which should also be displayed on the start up screen.  In
>   my case below it is 192.168.1.9.  This is the address of your Pi on
>   your network and what we will use to connect to your Pi from the
>   second machine.
>
> Second Machine Setup
>
> 1. Launch Remote Desktop Connection which can be found at Start->All Programs->Accessories->Remote Desktop Connection
> 2. Type in the IP Address for your Pi which you noted above.
> 3. Click Connect (you may get a security warning at this stage just click OK if you do.  After all it is your Pi on your network so
>      nothing to worry about security wise).
> 4. Leave the Module on the default of sesman-Xvnc and enter your username and password for your Pi.  (The default is pi and raspberry
>      if you haven't changed them).
> 5. Click OK and after a few moments you should be greeted my your Raspberry Pi's desktop!
> 6. When you are finished simply log-out from the Pi's desktop.

I found these steps from [here](http://www.raspberrypiblog.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-remote-desktop-from.html/) and they worked for me

Here is another way to use SSH:

> SSH into Raspberry Pi I generally log into my Raspberry Pi via SSH, or
>   Secure Shell to give it its full name. This allows command line
>   access, to your Raspberry Pi, from another computer. Although it is
>   possible to SSH into the Raspberry Pi from anywhere in the world, and
>   I do, this post only covers SSH access over the local network. I will
>   cover remote connection in a future blog post.
>
> Although this does not give access to a GUI (Graphical User
>   Interface), having access to the command line generally allows me to
>   do 95% of what I need to do. The other 5% I could probably do through
>   SSH, but sometimes you can't beat the comfort of a GUI. :-)
>
> First of all you need to know the IP address of the Raspberry Pi you
>   are wanting to log into. If you are unsure how to find this, then read
>   my blog post explaining how you can do this remotely using an
>   excellent tool called nmap.
>
> To SSH into your Raspberry Pi from a Linux or Apple Mac computer this
>   is very easy. You can just type your username and IP address into the
>   command line using the following format:
>
> ssh username@IPaddress
>
> Ensure you substitute username with the username you are wanting to
>   log into the remote computer with. The IP address should take the
>   format 192.168.1.66
>
> You may get a message explaining that the authenticity of the host
>   cannot be established, and if you are sure you want to continue
>   connecting.  You will only see this message the first time you SSH
>   into your Raspberry Pi. Simply type yes.
>
> You will then be asked for your password, enter the password for the
>   username you are trying to connect with.
>
> For windows this is a little more tricky to set up as it requires an
>   additional piece of software called PuTTY. However once installed this
>   is really simple to use.
>
> First go to the PuTTY website, www.putty.org, download and install the
>   software.
>
> Once installed load PuTTY
>
> Under Host Name (or IP address) type in the IP address you would like
>   to connect to. Select the SSH radio button. In the box under Saved
>   Sessions type in a name to identify this computer, such as Raspberry
>   Pi, and then click Save. Clicking on Open should now start your SSH
>   session.
>
> Next time you want to SSH into your Raspberry Pi you just need to load
>   PuTTY, click on the saved session to highlight it and then click Open.
>   Once you have typed in your password, when asked, you have remote
>   access to your Raspberry Pi.

I found these instructions from [here](http://trevorappleton.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/ssh-into-raspberry-pi.html)

Comment: I am not going to delete this answer, but note that duplicate answers are received negatively, and automatically flagged by the system as potential abuse. What you should have done is answered 1 of the questions and flagged the other as a duplicate..

Comment: @SteveRobillard I can't agree. The questioner has provided insufficient detail, so shouldn't get a detailed speculative answer.

Comment: @millways I was addressing the duplicate answer to multiple questions, not either of the specific questions, that is why i left it.